# iOS UIWebView forbid pulling outside the borders

Tags: ios, uiwebview

When I pull up or down my mobile version of site throught the WebView application I can see default gray background outside the page content. How can I forbid this action so user couldn't drag page out of page content borders?

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the grey areas, You can disable scroll thats seem be best way.

We currently have transparent background set on UIWebView

```
webview.opaque = NO;
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In the HTML

```
<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0style="background-color:transparent">
```